# Ахти — это что?

Tags: этимология

«Не ахти» означает *не так*, а что такое *ахти*?

Answer (score 3):

Само по себе это - *междометие*, означающее то же, что и "ах", помечаемое словарями как устаревшее или диалектное. В составе устойчивых разговорных выражений "не ахти (как/какой)" означает "не очень (хорошо/хороший)". Прямых указаний на образование этих выражений не попадалось, но можно предположить, что примерный исходный смысл был "никто не ахнул бы от радостного изумления, оценивая это", то междометие здесь фигурирует в своём положительном аспекте, но с добавлением отрицания.

Малый академический словарь приводит примеры с междометием "ахти" из классической литературы:

> Псари кричат: — Ахти, ребята, вор! — И вмиг ворота на запор. И.
>   Крылов, Волк на псарне.
>
> {Фекла:} Ахти, а ведь он {жених} все дожидается! Гоголь, Женитьба.

Answer (score 1):

Толковый словарь русского языка:
АХТИ, *межд.* (устар. и обл.). То же, что ***ах*** в 1 значении (выражает удивление, восхищение, испуг и другие чувства).
Не ахти как (разговорное) — не очень. Не ахти какой (разговорное) — не очень хороший.
Не ахти (разговорное) — то же, что не ахти как и не ахти какой.

Словарь В. Даля при поиске слова пишет: АХТИ́, см. ***ах***.
[**АХ**](http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Dal-term-642.htm)
междомет. изумления, удивления; радости, надежды; внезапности, испуга; горя, отчаяния.
**Ахти** ахти́ мне, восклицание горя, печали; увы; Ахти мне, все товарищи в тюрьме - что-то будет и мне? Охти-ахти! как-то замуж идти? Не а́хти мне, не на диво, не больно хорошо.

Словарь-справочник по пунктуации:
[**ахти**](https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/48)
междометие
Выделяется с двух сторон знаками препинания или оформляется как отдельное предложение.
*Ахти! вот до чего доводит безрассудство!* (О. Сомов. Оборотень)

*Царь кричит на весь базар:

«Ахти, батюшки, пожар!

Эй, решёточных сзывайте!

Заливайте! заливайте!»*
П. П. Ершов. Конёк-горбунок